# Responsive Web Design Align fluid and fixed Divs

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

```
<div id="headerText">
 <h1>Ur Title</h1>
</div>
<div id="headerIcon">
 <div id="icon">
  <div class="icon-list"></div>
  <div class="icon-list"></div>
  <div class="icon-list"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to align both the `headerText` and `headerIcon` side by side.
- headerIcon is fixed with size like 30px.
- headerText will expand the remaining width.

I've tried calc, it is working fine but I heard that calc is not supported in some android platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve the result by following structure.

keep your `#headerIcon` first with `float:right` style and then `#headerText`

```
<div id="headerIcon">
 <div id="icon">
  <div class="icon-list">1</div>
  <div class="icon-lienter code herest">2</div>
  <div class="icon-list">3</div>
 </div>
</div>    
<div id="headerText">
 <h1>Ur Title</h1>
</div>
```

**[working jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/ySQQ8/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping them in a div and make use of table display:

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/8jTb2/)

```
.wrap {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#headerText, #headerIcon {
    display: table-cell;
}
#headerIcon {
    background: red;
    width: 30px;
}
#headerText {
    background: silver;
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your quick reply. The answer you provided is working fine but inorder to implement the solution I have to change the the semantics of div.

Answer (score 0):

A solution in jQuery would be:

```
function alignWidth(){
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var iconwidth= $('#headerIcon').width();

var newWidth= windowWidth-iconwidth;

$('#headerText').css('width', newWidth);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    alignWidth();

    $(window).on('resize',function(){
            alignWidth();
        });

)};
```

Not tested...but should work if you can go for a jQuery solution...

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick reply. However I want to stick with CSS  only solution.

Comment: Okay. Maybe this helps someone else. Good luck with solving the problem :)